Why pushed ViewController has navigation controller in UIKit?
I'm not using storyboard and setup sceneDelegate like this
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
        let vc = A_ViewController()
        
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = vc
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()

        self.window = window
    }

In this codes, navigation controller isn't initialized. And, If I call navigation controller in A_ViewController like this:
print(self?.navigationController)

It prints "nil". And, Can't navigate to other ViewControllers.
It make sense because I didn't initialized navigation controller.
If edit sceneDelegate like this code:
let rootNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
window.rootViewController = rootNavigationController

And push other VC from A_ViewController, then
Pushed ViewController has it's own navigation controller
I didn't initialize pushed VC's navigationController. Why pushed VC has navigationController?

Not everything has to be initialised by you, you know? navigationController is a read only property - you can't "initialise" it in the first place.

navigationController is save way to get parent navigation controller from parentViewController

It is unclear what kind of answer you expect to get from "why pushed VC has navigationController?" Does "that's just what UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc) does" satisfy you?

@Sweeper Yes. If user shouldn't initialize Navigation Controller, why UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc) needed?

I never said. "user shouldn't initialize Navigation Controller" I was referring to the property navigationController (which you cannot initialise, not just shouldn't), not the class UINavigationController.

"Pushed ViewController has its own navigation controller" - no it does not. The pushed view controller is added to the existing navigation controller. Now both the original and the pushed view controllers are part of the navigation stack of the one original navigation controller created in the scene delegate.

UINavigationController:

A navigation controller is a container view controller that manages one or more child view controllers in a navigation interface

So it's a group of view controllers instead of a single view controller. Whenever you push a new controller, the internal controllers array in UINavigationController will append a new element. And vice versa, with pop the controller will be removed from this array. You can assume it's likely a singleton navigator in a workflow until you present a new workflow (without a new UINavigationController).
You can see this in the documentation. All these view controllers: Setting, General and Auto-Lock had the same UINavigationController instance, although it might be created once on the Setting screen.


Thanks for answer.
I have one more question. If that example is only other App's doing, navigation controller should be singleton. But, sometimes other navigation controller is needed. When to use other navigation controller?

As I said above, if your flow is something like Setting -> General -> Auto-Lock, it should stick together in a UINavigationController. The use case if there is another UINavigationController needed is from Auto-Lock, you also want to present, not push, another flow. Then you need to create another one UINavigationController here.
